# How can I find if a text value falls within a text range in an Oracle Database column?

Tags: oracle

I need to perform queries against a very poorly designed Oracle database (data warehouse) that has a column containing text strings of the form 'AB001-AB007'. I need to find matches for the text string 'AB002'. To make matters worse sometimes the text strings will include spaces like 'AB001 - AB007', sometimes they will include commas like 'AB001-AB002, AB004-AB007' etc.

My only implementation strategy thus far has been to select the primary key and this text string for the entire table and process outside of the database. There are 133,000 records in this table though, and this method isn't very performant. Can this be done in the database itself? Is there some regex way of doing this perhaps?

Can anyone point me at the name of this kind of query so I might do some more effective googling?

Answer (score 1):

You can unwrap the `,` with a row generator feeding `SUBSTR` / `INSTR` and then split up the two terms on either side of the hyphen so that a `BETWEEN` operator can be applied at the end:

```
WITH test AS (SELECT 'AB001-AB007' col FROM dual
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 'AB001-AB002, AB004-AB007' FROM dual)
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT RTRIM(SUBSTR(col,1,INSTR(col,'-')-1)) start_value,
               LTRIM(SUBSTR(col,INSTR(col,'-')+1)) end_value
          FROM (SELECT LTRIM(SUBSTR(','||col,INSTR(','||col,',',1,seq)+1,INSTR(','||col||',',',',1,seq+1) - (INSTR(','||col,',',1,seq)+1))) col
                  FROM test,
                       (SELECT LEVEL seq FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL < 10)))
 WHERE 'AB002' BETWEEN start_value AND end_value
```

This of course will not perform well, as it has to do this to 100% of the table every time. You'd be advised to create another table that materializes the `start_value`/`end_value` result of this logic for every row in the original table and refresh it when needed or after the original table is modified. Then you can index the derivative table and query it performantly.

Answer (score 0):

for exact AB002: value = 'AB002'
or
for records containing AB002: value like '%AB002%'

133,000 lines are nothing for oracle, should run in milliseconds

Comment: The problem is 'AB002' doesn't appear in 'AB001-AB007' which is what the column contains